# Create matrix of results from function applied to two vectors

Tags: r

If I have

```
x=c(2,4,8)
y=c(10,20,30)
f=sum
```

How do I get a matrix of function `f` applied to each combination of x and y elements? ie I want to get the matrix:

```
12, 14, 18
22, 24, 28
32, 34, 38
```

(Or the transpose of it)

I need something like `mapply`, but I need a matrix of results rather than a vector of element-wise function applications (eg `mapply(sum,x,y)` just gives `12, 24, 38`,  rather than a matix)

**EDIT**

Solution is:
`outer(x, y, '+')`, but not `outer(x, y, sum)`

`f=sum` was a really bad choice on my behalf. Instead,

```
x=c(2,4,8)
y=c(10,20,30)
f=function(a,b) {paste0(a,b)}  #A better function example than 'sum'

outer(x, y, f)
```

yields:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "210" "220" "230"
[2,] "410" "420" "430"
[3,] "810" "820" "830"
```

Thanks @tmfmnk and @Roland!

Comment: You could use `outer(x, y, `+`)`.

Comment: outer(x, y, "+") but that won't work with sum since the function must return a vector.

Comment: Thanks you two, that works with my actual example. (I probably should have used `f=function(a,b) {paste0(a,b)}` as my example, rather than `f=sum`).

Comment: Maybe `matrix(apply(expand.grid(x, y), 1, f), length(x), length(y))` ? Works also with `f=function(...) {paste0(..., collapse = "")}`

Comment: @GKi `outer` works just fine with `paste`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`outer` will also work.**  Actually `sum` and `+` are different when vectorised operations are carried out.  `sum` will result in aggregation of all elements of the given vector and a single element will be in output, whereas `+` carries out sum of corresponding elements of **two** vectors and output will also be a vector containing same number of elements.  Therefore,

```
x=c(2,4,8)
y=c(10,20,30)

outer(x, y, `+`)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   12   22   32
[2,]   14   24   34
[3,]   18   28   38
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Vectorize` over `f` when you use `outer`

```
> outer(x, y, Vectorize(f))
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "210" "220" "230"
[2,] "410" "420" "430"
[3,] "810" "820" "830"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```r
expand.grid( x,y ) %>%
    apply( 1, f ) %>%
    matrix( byrow=T, nrow=length(x) )
```

( .. which I see now was already in the comments)