# Applying function to 2 vectors to obtain a 2D matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

My question is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66562785/create-matrix-of-results-from-function-applied-to-two-vectors) but in Python instead of R. I couldn't find a similar question for python and so I'm asking this one.

I have 2 vectors (lists actually)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [5,6,7]
```

A defined function

```
def calc(i, j):
    return (i+j)/2
```

I want to apply the `calc` function to all the pairs of values in the vectors so that i obtain a matrix (preferably using `numpy` package).

The expected result in this case is

```
result = [
           [3,   3.5,   4],
           [3.5,  4,  4.5], 
           [4,   4.5,   5]
         ]
```

I would like to avoid list comprehensions and for loops to achieve this result.

Comment: You could take a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points) of the two arrays, then apply `.mean(axis=2)` to average each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use meshgrid

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [5, 6, 7]

def calc(i, j):
    return (i + j) / 2

A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)

result = calc(A, B)

print(result)
```

output:

```
[[3.  3.5 4. ]
 [3.5 4.  4.5]
 [4.  4.5 5. ]]
```